# How do I run multiple commands recursively through all sub folders using windows CMD or Batch?

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I have been trying to troubleshoot this hopefully simple issue for a few hours now.

Here is my batch script:

```
7z l *.zip > files.txt
grep -Po "(?<=2020)(.*)(?=.files)" files.txt > number.txt
set /p num=<number.txt
echo %num% > %num%.txt
del /f files.txt
del /f number.txt
```

This is clunky I am sure but it works. I have ~1,000 folders with 1 zip file in them. I am grabbing the number of files in the .zip files and saving that number as a .txt's file name inside of the zip directory.

My issue is I am trying to run this script through all the directories. I will show some things I have tried:

I tried calling the batch:

```
for /d %%i in (*) do ( cd "%%i" &  call "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TESTDIR\details.bat")
```

I have tried running a one line command:

```
for /d %%i in (*) do ( 7z l *.zip > files.txt & grep -Po "(?<=2020)(.*)(?=.files)" files.txt > number.txt & set /p num=<number.txt & echo %num% > %num%.txt & del /f files.txt & del /f number.txt)
```

And everything in between.

I am pulling my hair out over here, hopefully someone can help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: i don't see the problem. but in a one-liner you need to use `DELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: You should be able to use `for /f` on the `7z` line directly to get your number instead of all the temp files.  Something like `for /d %%i in (*) do for /f %%b in ('7z l *.zip^|grep -Po "^(?^<=2020^)^(.*^)^(?=.files^)"') do echo %%b>%%b.txt`  I might have the ^ escapes wrong.

Comment: I would assume @avery_larry, that as the `-Po` option is already doublequoted, that none of it requires escaping, just your 'pipe to grep' character should be. _If anything did, I would look initially at the closing parentheses, (opening parentheses should never need escaping, there's nothing special about them to cmd.exe or the `for` command)_.

Comment: @Compo That sounds reasonable.  I never quite keep the exact rules straight in all the different places -- especially with closed parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I decided it was easier to just call the bat in each folder. This is working. Thanks all for the help.

```
call zipdetails.bat
for /r /d %%x in (*) do (
    pushd "%%x"
    call zipdetails.bat
    popd
)
```